# How can i use a variable in sbt

Tags: gradle, sbt, dependency-management

I am creating a build.sbt for my project and it has dependencies mentioned like

```
 libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
                       "com.typesafe.akka"          % "akka-actor_2.11"                         % "2.3.15",
                       "org.scalaz"                 % "scalaz-core_2.11"                        % "7.2.0",
                       "org.scalactic"              % "scalactic_2.11"                          % "2.2.6" ,
                       "org.scalatest"              % "scalatest_2.11"                          % "2.2.6"  % "test",
                       "org.scalamock"              % "scalamock-scalatest-support_2.11"        % "3.2.2"  % "test",
                       "org.springframework" % "spring-context" % "4.1.6.RELEASE",
                       "org.springframework" % "spring-beans" % "4.1.6.RELEASE",
                       "org.springframework" % "spring-core" % "4.1.6.RELEASE",
                       "org.springframework" % "spring-context" % "4.1.6.RELEASE",
                       "org.springframework" % "spring-web" % "4.1.6.RELEASE",
                       "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "14.0.1",
                       "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.3",
                       "commons-lang" % "commons-lang" % "2.5",
                       "net.sf.opencsv" % "opencsv" % "2.3",
                       "com.thoughtworks.xstream" % "xstream" % "1.4.8",
                       "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "1.4",
                       "commons-codec" % "commons-codec" % "1.6",
                       "commons-collections" % "commons-collections" % "3.2.2",
                       "commons-logging" % "commons-logging" % "1.1.1",
                       "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.3.3",
                       "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpmime" % "4.3.3",
                       "jmdns" % "jmdns" % "0.2",
                       "com.sun.mail" % "javax.mail" % "1.5.4",
                       "junit" % "junit" % "4.12" % "test"
    )
```

I want to specify the versions elsewhere  as variables and refer to those(variables) in the dependencies.
Can that be done as in gradle ?

Comment: SBT build is just a code, so you can do anything in it. E.g. read some file or env variables, and just use them in `libraryDependencies`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Declare a `val` in your `build.sbt` and you can refer to it in the dependencies. Example: https://github.com/softwaremill/bootzooka/blob/master/build.sbt#L18